# How should I name property associating object with another object in ASP .NET MVC (relation one to zero)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have model class `Article` and a class `ApplicationUser`. I would like to remeber who is an author of the article.

I know that ASP .NET MVC highly relies on name conventions.

Should I call property(in `class Article`):

```
    [DisplayName("Author")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

or

```
    [DisplayName("Author")]
    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
```

in order to Entity Framework understand my intentions?

Comment: Both will do. I would recommend using second way as it is closer to real world association.

Comment: @AshishCharan Thank you that's what I wanted but wasn't sure if it would work.